# Cache JSP based on URL parameter

Tags: java, performance, jsp, caching

I have a jsp file pageshow.jsp and the parameter id,

Is there any way to cache the jsp file in server-side based on the url parameter

Requesting  page  pageshow.jsp?id=100 get from cache instead of building from server
Requesting  page  pageshow.jsp?id=200 get from cache instead of building from server

Above two pages should have different cache content since their parameter are different

This may avoid the rebuilding the jsp file in server side and also decrease the server load

Comment: JPSs are built (into Java classes) only once, at the first time they are being accessed. What do you want to achieve by "caching"? If page creation is very costly, you might rather check if you can cache the results of e.g. database operations required.

Comment: +1 @f_puras . JSPs are compiled once. You possibly can pre compile JSP.

Comment: @f_puras i want cached the JSTL/scriptlet result also . eg. in page i show Product ID :-<%= request.getparamter %>, in this case i want to cache the generated output by this part of code

Comment: You want to cache a request parameter value on the server? Beg your pardon, but I doubt you know just **what** is causing server load. Why not share your JSP code with us, so we know what we are talking about?

Comment: @f_puras simply, i want to convert the dynamic page to static page and save into disk , once the same page again get requested by client with same GET parameter , instead of going to controller or dao , just read from static page,this will reduce the server side load on building the page right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd take a look at using a `CachingHttpFilter` similar to what AlexR has proposed, but look at using the HTTP headers to control the caching rather than storing data in a roll-your-own-content-cache.

[This article](http://www.javablog.fr/javaweb-set-cache-control-in-reponse-with-http-filter-httpcachefilter.html) explains nicely how to go about comparing the `If-Modified-Since` HTTP header when a URL is requested subsequent times. It's then up to your Filter to send back a `HTTP 304` response.

> **Comparison of dates:**
>
> The client asks the server to a specific page: if the client has
>   already read the page, it sends a request (to server) containing the
>   last modification date of its cached page (eg “If-Modified-Since:
>   21/07/2002 13:47:24 GMT”);There also the header If-Unmodified-Since;
>
> The server compares this date given by the client with the last
>   modified date of requested page:
>
> if the page on the server has the same date, then the server informs
>   the client that it can use the version’s page in its cache (“HTTP/1.1
>   304 Not Modified”). The exchange between client and server stops
>   there;
>
> if the page on the server is newer, then the server informs the client
>   of the change (“Last-modified: 21/06/2012 08:45:37 p.m. GMT”) and sent
>   this page to client. The browser stores the date of last change of the
>   page.

You will also want to look at the [`ETag` HTTP Header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag).

Unfortunately caching sounds simple but is often difficult to get right. Tuning your database queries is often the best place to start with improving your application performance.

Answer (score 2):

You can create `CachingHttpFilter` that is mapped to this JSP page only and does the following:

- checks whether cached content exists
- if exists just returns it
- if does not exist calls `chain.doFilter(request, response);` that will go to the requested JSP. But passes there special response (response wrapper) that stores all bytes returned by the JSP and caches them.